# Remove duplicates of set of characters in string - Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string `'1a1b1c1d3e3e3e1f1g2h2h1i1j1k1l1m1n4o4o4o4o1p1q2r2r1s2t2t2u2u1v1w1x1y1z'`
and I want to remove all of the duplicates of these charterers: `3e, 4o, 2r` etc.
How can I do that in Python?

Comment: is there any specific string len to remove?

Comment: all of those are 2 characters. Its always a number and a letter next to it

Comment: Not sure if there's a builtin that can handle this scenario. But a crude way to do it would be to do `x = x[:x.find(y)+len(y)] + x[x.find(y)+len(y):].replace(y, '')` where `x` is your original string and `y` is the desired duplicates to be removed no matter what cost. Add error handling etc to catch `-1` positions etc.

Comment: There's also very little constraints here. Which is worrying. For instance, what if you're actually looking to keep the 2:d occurance? or the last?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str_='1a1b1c1d3e3e3e1f1g2h2h1i1j1k1l1m1n4o4o4o4o1p1q2r2r1s2t2t2u2u1v1w1x1y1z'
seen = set()
result = []
n=2
for i in range(0,len(str_),n):
    item=str_[i:i+n]
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        result.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty crude way of doing it.
But it seams to do the job without begin to complicated.

This also assumes that it's known character compositions you need to remove. You didn't mention that you need to remove **all** duplicates, only a set of known ones.

```
x = '1a1b1c1d3e3e3e1f1g2h2h1i1j1k1l1m1n4o4o4o4o1p1q2r2r1s2t2t2u2u1v1w1x1y1z'
for y in ['3e', '4o', '2r']:
    x = x[:x.find(y)+len(y)] + x[x.find(y)+len(y):].replace(y, '')
print(x)
```

Finds the first occurance of your desired object *(`3e` for instance)* and builds a new version of the string up to and including that object, and prepends the string with the rest of the original string but with replacing your object with a empty string.

This is a bit slow, but again, gets the job done.
No error handling here tho so be wary of `-1` positions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension and set to do this in the following way:

`s = '1a1b1c1d3e3e3e1f1g2h2h1i1j1k1l1m1n4o4o4o4o1p1q2r2r1s2t2t2u2u1v1w1x1y1z'
s = [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s) - 1, 2)]
s = set(s)`

Hope it helps